# Is there a way to create a new instance on localhost on a different port?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I would like to create a new instance on MySql and use a different port on localhost. Is that possible or MySql only runs locally on 3306? Why?

I could not find any articles related to that.

I am using MySql Workbench on Ubuntu 20.04.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How to run multiple instances of MySQL Server on one server is in the MySQL manual: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/multiple-servers.html

Comment: Thank you very much!